# Converting keyCode to actual key and code values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keycode

**Background**: I have stored a key modifier and a keycode value, like so `["shiftKey", 32]` (=> shift+space), or `[undefined, 32]` (=> space) on the user's machine. This array that I have stored acts as a "hotkey", i.e., I'm supposed to detect when user presses any key that matches with the hotkey. So, I'm supposed to do something when user presses Shift+Space, for example. Functionality wise it is working fine so far, as the keyCode's still match. The only problem is that...

**Problem**: I cannot properly display the `keyCode` in text form. ("?" key has `keyCode=191` on my system, but it does not display correctly on doing `String.fromCharCode`, obviously)

**My proposed solution:** convert the `[key modifier, keyCode]` array  to `[key modifier, key, code]` (since `key` and `code` properties can easily be displayed as text). The conversion code that I will write will run on the user's machine (it's a Chrome extension), so there is no worry of not having the locale information of the user. The problem is: how exactly to perform this conversion?

**My attempt:** dispatch programmatic keyboard events to a fake textbox based on the `keyCode`, and using the `key` and `code` values generated from there as the conversion result. However, the only [properly working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/termi/yjc5F/) I could find required me to actually supply the `key` and `code` values, otherwise they would be undefined.

**Final question:** how else to perform this conversion? Or is there any other workaround to achieve what I want to?

Comment: Some thoughts: 1) Aren't there existing libraries for that? 2) The most compatible thing is `which`, not `keyCode`, and it will work in the foreseeable future (for web compatibility reasons) regardless of what MDN or anyone else says. 3) document.execCommand with `insertText` or `insertHTML` parameter is often a better solution to supply text into web pages than faking key presses.

Comment: @wOxxOm 3) I think you misunderstood: the `[key modifier, key code]` pair I have stored in the database is a "hotkey", i.e., I'm supposed to detect when user presses any key that matches with the hotkey. So, I'm supposed to do something when user presses Shift+Space, for example. Functionality wise it is working fine so far, as the keyCode's still match. The only problem is that i cannot display the keycode properly as text to the user.